# Resolving generics with interface as type parameter in Autofac

Tags: c#, generics, autofac

After reading tons of documentation and questions from here I'm still stuck with the following. These are the interfaces/implementations registered with Autofac:

```
public interface ITestService<T>
{
}

public class TestService<T> : ITestService<T>
{
}

public interface ITest<TService, T>
    where TService : ITestService<T>
{
}

public class Test<TService, T> : ITest<TService, T>
    where TService : ITestService<T>
{
}
```

The registration is as following, where builder is a ContainerBuilder instance and it updates a central IComponentRegistry:

```
builder.RegisterGeneric(typeof(TestService<>)).As(typeof(ITestService<>)).InstancePerLifetimeScope();

builder.RegisterGeneric(typeof(Test<,>)).As(typeof(ITest<,>)).InstancePerLifetimeScope();
```

**Now this works** (where _componentContext is an IComponentContext instance):

```
_componentContext.Resolve<ITest<TestService<MyType>, MyType>>();
```

**This doesn't** (throwing ComponentNotRegisteredException):

```
_componentContext.Resolve<ITest<ITestService<TNodeToNodeConnectorRecord>, TNodeToNodeConnectorRecord>>();
```

Any tips on how resolving could work without knowing the implementation of ITestService? Since

```
_componentContext.Resolve<ITestService<MyType>>();
```

works as expected, using its type may be used somehow but I haven't succeeded.

**Update, exception details:**
The exception thrown is as following:

```
"The requested service 'MyProject.ITest`2[[MyProject.ITestService`1[[MyProject.MyType, MyProject, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]], MyProject, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null],[MyProject.MyType, MyProject, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]]' has not been registered."
```

Stack trace:

```
   at Autofac.ResolutionExtensions.Resolve(IComponentContext context, Service service, IEnumerable`1 parameters)
   at Autofac.ResolutionExtensions.Resolve(IComponentContext context, Type serviceType, IEnumerable`1 parameters)
   at Autofac.ResolutionExtensions.Resolve[TService](IComponentContext context, IEnumerable`1 parameters)
   at Autofac.ResolutionExtensions.Resolve[TService](IComponentContext context)
   at MyProject.SomeController`4.Execute(RequestContext requestContext) in d:\SomeController.cs:line 55
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerBase.System.Web.Mvc.IController.Execute(RequestContext requestContext)
   at System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.<>c__DisplayClass6.<>c__DisplayClassb.<BeginProcessRequest>b__5()
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.<>c__DisplayClass1.<MakeVoidDelegate>b__0()
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.<>c__DisplayClass8`1.<BeginSynchronous>b__7(IAsyncResult _)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResult`1.End()
   at System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.<>c__DisplayClasse.<EndProcessRequest>b__d()
   at System.Web.Mvc.SecurityUtil.<GetCallInAppTrustThunk>b__0(Action f)
   at System.Web.Mvc.SecurityUtil.ProcessInApplicationTrust(Action action)
   at System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult result)
   at Orchard.Mvc.Routes.ShellRoute.HttpAsyncHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult result) in D:\MyProject.SomeRoutes.cs:line 148
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)
```

The code executing the resolve calls is actually in the Execute() method of an ASP.NET MVC controller.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Please, make sure you don't have a typo in your configs. If there are no typos, post the exception details. I've tried your code and it works fine with Autofac 2.5.2.830, .NET 4

Comment: Thanks, that's strange. If that matters, this all happens inside an Orchard CMS module. This means there is no configuration I'm aware of.

Comment: I've added the exception details. Thanks for your time! If it matters, the Autofac version I'm using is 2.2.4.900.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, your version of Autofac has a bug: [Generic parameters constrained as generic interfaces fail to resolve.](http://code.google.com/p/autofac/issues/detail?id=330).

It has been fixed, supposedly in 2.5.1. You'll have to upgrade to use the feature.

Or you can try a workaround:

```
public interface ITestService<T>
{
}

public class TestService<T> : ITestService<T>
{
}

public interface ITest<T>
{
  ITestService<T> TestService { get; }
}

public class Test<T> : ITest<T>
{
  readonly ITestService<T> _TestService;

  public Test(ITestService<T> testService)
  {
    _TestService = testService;
  }

  public ITestService<T>
  {
    get
    {
      return this._TestService;
    }
  }
}

builder.RegisterGeneric(typeof(TestService<>)).As(typeof(ITestService<>)).InstancePerLifetimeScope();
builder.RegisterGeneric(typeof(Test<>)).As(typeof(ITest<>)).InstancePerLifetimeScope();
...

_componentContext.Resolve<ITest<TNodeToNodeConnectorRecord>>();

// if you need to specify the ITestService type to use:
var testService = _componentContext.Resolve<TestService<TNodeToNodeConnectorRecord>>();
var test = _componentContext.Resolve<Func<ITestService<TNodeToNodeConnectorRecord>, ITest<TNodeToNodeConnectorRecord>>>()(testService);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, wonderful! I think the Orchard Team will update Autofac in the next release.